# Understanding why a vector topology is completely determined by any local base.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

**What is shown below is a reference from the text *Functional Analysis* by Walter Rudin.**

If $X$ s a vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ then  the following notation well be used
$$
x+A=\{x+a:a\in A\}\\
x-A:=\{x-a:a\in A\}\\
A+B:=\{a+b:a\in A\wedge b\in B\}\\
\lambda A:=\{\lambda a:a\in A\}
$$
for any $A,B\subseteq X$, for any $x\in\ X$ and for any $\lambda\in\Bbb F$.

> **Definition**
>
> If $\tau$ is a topology on a vector space $X$ such that
>
> 1. every point of $X$ is a closed set
> 2. the vector space operation are continuous with respect to $\tau$
>
> we say that $X$ is a topological vector space equipped with the vector topology $\tau$.

So we note that the condition $1$ imply that any topological vector space will be $T_1$ but many authors omitted the above condition from the definition of a topological vector space.

> **Proposition**
>
> Let be $X$ a topological vector space over the field $\Bbb F$ and for some $v\in X$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb F$ we define the $v$-traslation and $\lambda$-multiplication functions through the condition
> $$
> T_v(x):=x+v\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,M_\lambda(x):=\lambda x
> $$
> for any $x\in X$. So the above two defined functions are homeomorphisms.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.

One consequence of the above proposition is that every vector topology $\tau$ is translation-invariant, that is a set $E\subseteq X$ is open if and only if each of its translates $v+E$ is open and thus $\tau$ is completely determined by any local base so that the open sets of $X$ are then precisely those that are unions of translates of memebrs of any local base.

So I like to discuss the last statement: indeed since a neighborhood is not union of basic neighborhoods then the image of local base undera traslation is not a base so what means that a vector topology is completely determined by any local base? Could someone help me to understand this statement, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a local base at $x$, $\mathscr{B}_y=\{B+(y-x):B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a local base at $y$, and $\bigcup_{y\in X}\mathscr{B}_y$ is a base for the topology of $X$. In other words, we can get a base for the topology and therefore the whole topology directly from that one local base $\mathscr{B}_x$.

Comment: +1. To the OP, the point is that once we know a single local base we know the entire topology; it's in this sense that any local base determines the whole topology (analogously to how if $V,W$ are vector spaces and $f:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear map, the behavior of $f$ on any basis of $V$ determines the whole of $f$).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So fixed $x$ for any $y$ we observe that $x\in T^{-1}_{(y-x)}[U]=(x-y)+U$ for any neighborhoods $U$ of $y$ and so there exist $B\in\mathscr B_x$ such that $B\subseteq T^{-1}_{(y-x)}[U]$ so that $T_{(y-x)}[B]\subseteq U$ from which we conclude that $\mathscr B_y=T_{(y-x)}[\mathscr B_x]$ is a local base for $y$ (**right**?) but unfortunately I do not see why $\bigcup_{y\in X}\mathscr B_y$ is a base for $X$ so could you explain this, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Perhaps I understood. If $A$ is open then for any $y\in A$ there exist $B\in\mathscr B_x$ such that $y\in T_{(y-x)}[B]\subseteq A$ and so $A$ is union of this such opens, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: The argument in your first comment is fine. In any topological space $X$ it is true that if $\mathscr{B}_x$ is a local base at $x$ for each $x\in X$, then $\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{x\in X}\mathscr{B}_x$ is a base for $X$: if $U$ is an open nbhd of some $x\in X$, there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}_x\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

Comment: Okay, all clear now. Thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!